# path defining in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, nodes, gulp-watch

I have my project based folder as follows.

```
root_Folder
    |______project_folder1
    |         |___dist
    |         |    |____js
    |         |          |___app.js(converted)
    |         |___src
    |         |    |____js
    |         |          |___app.js
    |         |___index.html
    |______project_folder2
    |         |___dist
    |         |    |____js
    |         |          |___app.js(converted)
    |         |___src
    |         |    |____js
    |         |           |___app.js
    |         |___index.html  
    |______project_folder3,4,etc.
    |_____gulpfile.js
```

here I have a root folder. under the root folder I have project folder with es6 and they will we converted and converted file will be saved in dist folder.

project folder will be created dynamically. since there will be new project folders I cannot mention a correct path in between root folder and the **src** folder of each project. how can I define a path. I want to find the changes of JavaScript files in **src** folder in each project. not the **dist** folder..

I cannot use `'./rootFolder/**/*'` since this will detect all the Javascript files inside the project including the dist folder.

need help thank you.

Comment: you could simply do './rootFolder/**/src/**/*.js' there is a discussion here https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/306

Comment: thanks a lot. I have tried that ones, but didn't worked at that time. but now its working perfectly. thank you :)

Comment: hello user93 how can I be your friend. :)

Comment: I have added the same response in the comment as an answer for future reference of others please accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply do `'./rootFolder/**/src/**/*.js'` there is a discussion [here](http://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/306)